# How to let x axis title still show on the bottom when setting fontsize attribute in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying set up title fontsize of x-axis in highcharts, it always change the position from bottom to the top of the chart, but there's no problem if I assign font size of y-axis' title style.

There is a example I mentioned, which is modified from a highcharts demo code.
http://jsfiddle.net/bzvBN/

```
       xAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Total fruit consumption',
                style : {
                    fontSize : 'large'
                }
            },
            categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
        },
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I advice to use values in pixels, instead of "large"

```
style : {
                    fontSize : '40px'
                }
```

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/bzvBN/1/